# print one variable from many gnuplot fits to one txt file

Tags: gnuplot

I have a bash script that I wrote to graph and fit lots of data files in gnuplot that is looped by the following

```
filelist=`ls -1 *.txt`
for filename in  $filelist ; do
    gnuplot_script
done
```

I would like to print one variable, "A", from the final fit parameters of each fit and have them all in 1 file. I attempted to do so within the gnuplot script (at the very end of the script).

```
set print "var.prn"
print "$filename" , " = " , A
```

When I run the script, it ends up with a file "var.prn" with just the final parameter from the last file iterated from the loop. It seems like it creates a file with what I want in it, but then overwrites it with each iteration so the end result is just 1 line.

edit: even having it print the variable A from each iteration to separate files would be great. I could combine the files in the end.

Comment: You are probably looking for this: [How to add data from gnuplot to an existing file without overwiting the contents of said file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196592/how-to-add-data-from-gnuplot-to-an-existing-file-without-overwiting-the-contents).

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks!